# Может ли союз «и» быть разделительным? И если да, то в каких случаях?

Tags: союзы

Просьба ответить на вопрос: может ли союз «и» быть разделительным? И если да, то в каких случаях? Зашёл спор с одним филологом (или якобы филологом), который утверждает, что в определенных случаях может. Случаи привести отказался. В справочниках таких данных не нашлось (союз «и» они относят только к соединительным). Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться - стало очень интересно.

Comment: Раз отказался - значит не смог. Потому что  союз "и" не относится к разделительным.

Comment: *Раз отказался - значит не смог* - это ошибочная постановка вопроса. Раз отказался, значит отказался.

Answer (score 4):

Союз **и** не может быть разделительным. Ни в одной грамматике союз **и** не относиться к разделительным. 
Список разделительных союзов: или, либо, а то, не то, а не то; или… или, либо... либо; ли... ли, ли... или, хоть... хоть, что... что, будь то... или; а то и, а может (быть) и; не... так, если (и) не... то; а может (быть), может (быть)... может (быть), может (быть)... а может (быть); не то... не то, то ли... то ли; то... то.

[См. Русская корпусная грамматика.](http://rusgram.ru/)

Comment: Неубедительно. Серж не может читать **все грамматики**. Но дело не в этом, конечно. Здесь вопрос терминологии. И её примерами или списками не проверяют.

Answer (score 3):

И не то вправду сразу уснул, не то прикинулся. Здесь присоединительный союз И перед разделительным НЕ ТО...НЕ ТО.

Пока не получается найти подходящий вариант с разделительным союзом И.

Comment: Не найдете Вы. Семантика союза исключает. В лучшем случае обнаружите нечто, что можно будет *объявить* таким случаем. Но никак не реальной разделительной конструкцией.

Comment: Один такой случай - см.. в моем ответе.

Answer (score 3):

Иван, давайте от печки. Грамматики - это, конечно, хорошо, но надо разобраться в понятиях. Скорее всего недоразумение - терминологического плана, Ваш собеседник не так понимает смысл понятия "разделительный союз". 
По определению "*Разделительные союзы выражают отношения взаимоисключения, чередования действий, явлений, признаков*".
"И" по семантике не имеет подобных значений.

Есть предположение (робкое), что Ваш собеседник мог быть филологом от программирования или математиком. Ну еще вариант - юристом. Там значения союзов "и" и "или" далеко не всегда соответствуют привычным бытовым представлениям.

Например.

"Выберите все желтые и круглые предметы" - означает выбрать из некоторого списка все **желтые круглые** предметы.

**"Выберите все желтые и зеленые предметы"** - означает выбрать из некоторого списка все предметы, которые **либо желтые, либо зеленые** (по умолчанию предполагаем, что предметы одноцветные).

Понятно, что в последнем случае "И" де-факто выступает в роли *разделительного* союза. Но только математику или юристу придет в голову подобный пример толковать именно так. И то только потому, что в их формальном языке фраза будут звучать "выбрать все желтые **или** зеленые предметы".

Филологи же и все, оперирующие бытовыми представлениями, даже не задумываясь над этим парадоксом, считают "И" союзом соединительным, поскольку он **соединяет** множества желтых и зеленых предметов.

Т.е. в этом (и еще нескольких) примерах математики "навешивают" союз на свойства, а филологи и простые смертные - на множества элементов с этими свойствами. В этом принципиальная разница подходов, порождающая невозможность понимания союза "И" как разделительного с точки зрения "здравого смысла", но только не строгой формальной логики.

Где-то я писал об этом подробно, здесь повторять не буду, если не попросите. Попробую поискать, если найду, дам ссылку.

Разумеется, это всего лишь одно из весьма слабых предположений о том, что имел в виду Ваш оппонент. Лучше всего спросить у него самого.

Comment: 1) Выберите либо желтые, либо зеленые предметы. Союз ЛИБО...ЛИБО - разделительный. Я ВЫБИРАЮ только желтые или только  зеленые. 2) Выберите все желтые и зеленые предметы" . Я ВЫБИРАЮ все предметы, которые ЯВЛЯЮТСЯ либо желтыми, либо зелеными. Во втором случае действия разные.

Comment: 1) а я тут при чем? Давайте мой пример комментировать, а не Ваш. 2) Да сколько угодно. Действия разные потому что союз несет разный смысл. 3) Вы математик? Я говорю о возможных представлениях о смысле союза, а то, как его трактуют на бытовом уровне, я и сам знаю.

Comment: *Vera*: **банан, арбуз, огурец, баклажан**. *Выберите все желтые и круглые предметы. Вы что выберете? А если *"Выберите все желтые и зеленые предметы"?

Comment: 1) Банан, арбуз.  2) Банан, огурец. И что теперь?

Comment: Ничего. У вас оригинальное мышление. В первом случае, как минимум. А если *"Выберите все желтые **или** круглые предметы?"*

Comment: Большинство в первом случае не выберут ничего. Поскольку будут искать предметы одновременно желтые и круглые. Ну там грейпфрут...

Comment: "Найдите в тексте все буквы `о` перед `р` и после `в`" -- большинство людей будут искать буквосочетания `во` и `ор`, и только т.н. "математики" -- триграммы `вор`. Ну и естесственно, на "выберите все жёлтые и круглые предметы" нормальные люди будут искать все "все жёлтые предметы" и "все круглые предметы" (объединение множеств), и только т.н. "математики" -- предметы, которые являются круглыми и жёлтыми одновременно.

Comment: *большинство людей будут искать буквосочетания во и ор, и только т.н. "математики" -- триграммы вор* - Не уверен. Ни в людях, ни в математиках. Впрочем, большинство скорее всего уточнит, что имеется в вижу. Но, допустим, все так. Что это доказывает? Только то, что я прав в своем ответе. Вопрос терминологии. И понимания.